# Java, extracting words between $ symbol

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Using Java, I want to extract the words between the dollarsign symbol `$`.

For example:

```
String = " this is first attribute $color$. this is the second attribute $size$"
```

I want to pull out the strings: `color` and `size` and put them into a List.

I have tried:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\$) .* (\\$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
```

but I get the output:

```
"$color$.this is the second attribute $size$"
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the regex you are using is greedy and consumes everything beginning at the first `$` until the last `$` in your string. You have to add a `?` after the `*` to make the regex nongreedy:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(.*?)\\$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++)
    result.add(matcher.group(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem that `.*` matches **any** symbol. So your pattern result is correct as at the beginning and at the end is the dollar sign.

If your variable between dollars is just alphanumeric use `\$\w+\$`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the word does not contain dollars: `(\$)[^$]*(\$)`

Or, instead of greedy, use a reluctant match-all `(\$) .*? (\$)`

Comment: Can you tell me, what is implication of those brackets wrapping `(\$)`, what is different between this and my answer?

Comment: The brackets are not necessary. I guess OP put them there for semantical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex. It should give what is expected.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\$(.*?)\$");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use non-greedy qualifier in your pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(.*?)\\$");
```

Note the question mark after the asterisk. Also, you may consider using `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Use non-greedy matching to find the smallest match and you can use groups to extract only the word without "$":

```
"\\$(.*?)\\$"
```

The word is then found in the first group:

```
matcher.group(1)
```