# Java - Extract everything between [* ... *]

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
[* content I want *] 
[ more content ]
```

I would like to read the file and be able to extract `content I want`. The best I could do is below but it returns

`[ more content ]`

Please note that both `content I want` and `more content` contain brackets and parenthesis but they never contain `[*` or `*]`.

```
public static String parseFile(String src) throws IOException
{
    String s = "";
    File f = new File(src);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    sc.useDelimiter("\\[\\*([^]]+)\\*\\]");
    s= sc.next();
    sc.close();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Note exactly a dupe, but same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174624/java-extacting-words-between-symbol?rq=1

Comment: Use matcher and find rather than a scanner.

Comment: If your content can contain brackets, why do you exclude them?  `[^]]+`  Shouldn't that part be `.+` instead?

Comment: what's wrong with this `\[\* (.+) \*\]`

Comment: I'd also like to add that you may find the site https://www.debuggex.com/ useful for regex problems.  You  can paste a regex in there, and it will visually show you what it matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regular expression should work:

```
\[\s*\*\s*(.*?)\s*?\*\s*\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/uC4lH9/3

You can use it like this (Java 8):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexExample {
public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\[\\s*\\*\\s*(.*?)\\s*?\\*\\s*\\]");

public static List<String> parse(String fileContent) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(fileContent);
    List<String> foundData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        foundData.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return foundData;
}

public static void printOutList(List<? extends CharSequence> list) {
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printOutList(parse("[ this will not match ] [ * YOU WILL BE MATCHED!!!11 * ] [* you as well *] [*you too*]" +
            " [           *              this as well       *] [this * will * not]"));
}
}
```

Output:

```
YOU WILL BE MATCHED!!!11
you as well
you too
this as well
```

See it yourself: https://ideone.com/ldclWA

Comment: This isn't right. If you use OP's example input, it matches "content I want" and "more content", but OP only wants "content I want"

Comment: @ezig Oh now I get it.